# Requisição JsonResult com tipo decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

Porque quando envio uma requisição com um tipo decimal(3) o "Ponto" é eliminado, vejam no campo **INSS** que é um valor decimal, por exemplo: eu digito `1,69` quando faz um bind no modelo o ponto é eliminado e transformado em `1690` qdo deveria ser `1.690` ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui é o Controller (lá no javascript eliminei alguns campos para ficar mais limpo e fácil o entendimento):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="inss" id="inss" value="" class="form-control" />
```

**Javascript**

```
 $("#btnCadastrar").on("click", function () {
                 var _fornecedor = { 
                 "FornecedorID": $("#FornecedorID").val(),
                 "Imposto":[]
             };
             var _inss = parseFloat($("#inss").val().replace(",", ".")).toFixed(3);

             _fornecedor.Imposto.push({
                 "INSS": _inss
             });

             $.ajax({
                 url: "/Fornecedor/IncluirJSON",
                 type: "post",
                 dataType: "json",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 processData: false,
                 data: JSON.stringify(_fornecedor),
                 success: function (data) {
                     window.location.href = "/Fornecedor/Index";
                 },
                 error: function (result) {
                     alert(result.responseText);
                 }
             });
         });
```

**MODELO**

```
public class Imposto
    {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public int ImpostoID { get; set; }
        public int FornecedorID { get; set; }
        public decimal? INSS { get; set; }
        public virtual Fornecedor Fornecedor { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Pelo que eu sei o decimal e escrito com **.** (Ponto) em C#, ou seja você deveria passa 1.69 no lugar de 1,69.

Answer (score 1):

Solução:

```
var _inss = $("#inss").val().replace("%", "").replace(",", ".") == '' ? "0.00" : parseFloat($("#inss").val().replace("%", "").replace(",", ".")).toFixed(3);
```

e em seguida:

```
_fornecedor.Imposto.push({
            "INSS": JSON.parse(_inss)
        });
```